# How to update mix:versionable node property

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I am using jack rabbit OAK implementation for CMS, where I am versioning some file nodes using below code:

```
session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager().checkout(file.getPath());
// operation for saving file content and setting file node properties
session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager().checkin(file.getPath());
```

By using above, I have created 3 version of particular file with setting their custom properties, i.e; 1.0, 1.1, 1.2.
Now I want to update some property values from version 1.1
How to update versionable node property value using jack rabbit OAK implementation?

Comment: You may want to read <https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/15_Versioning.html>

Comment: @JulianReschke, I am trying to update all base version node property using below  code:
    
    final Version v =               session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager().getBaseVersion(node.getPath());
    v.setProperty(name, valuesList.toArray(new Value[0]));

But I am getting below error:
javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: Item is protected

Comment: @JulianReschke I think I am getting nt:version nodeType node, and I am trying to update its property, so getting error. Is there any way to update base version's property value?

Comment: Version storage is essentially frozen. That's the point of Version Control, no?

Comment: yeah, That's the point of Version Control.